# Scalatest 2.10 with akka.TestKit, weird compilier error

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm using the scala IDE for development. I have a few actors which I'm testing out. I wrote one scala test suite with the following definition and didn't have any problems:

```
import org.scalatest._
import akka.testkit._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatest._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.Props 
import filters._

class ReaderSourceTest( _system: ActorSystem ) extends TestKit( _system ) with FunSuiteLike with BeforeAndAfterAll with ImplicitSender {
  import ReaderSource._

  //Must have a zero argument constructor
  def this() = this( ActorSystem( "ReaderSourceSuite" ) )

  override def afterAll = TestKit.shutdownActorSystem( system )

  test( "Reader should be alive as an actor" ) {
    val reader = system.actorOf( Props( classOf[ ReaderSource ], "dummy/file/name" ), "tstReaderA" )

    reader ! Ping( "Hello" )
    expectMsg( Pong( "Hello" ) )
  }
}
```

I then created another test file to test another actor which goes like this:

```
import socketclient._
import org.scalatest._
import akka.testkit._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.Props
import org.scalatest.fixture.FunSuiteLike
import java.net.InetAddress
import org.kdawg.CommProtocol.CommMessages._
import org.kdawg.CommProtocol.CommMessages

class NetworkTest( _system: ActorSystem ) extends TestKit( _system ) with FunSuiteLike with BeforeAndAfterAll with ImplicitSender
{
  import NetworkTalker._
  def this() = this( ActorSystem( "NetworkTalkerTest") )

  override def afterAll = TestKit.shutdownActorSystem( system )
  test( "Can Send a Packet" )
  {
     val net = system.actorOf( NetworkTalker.props("10.1.0.5", 31000), "TestA" )  
     val pktBuilder = CommMessage.newBuilder
     pktBuilder.setType( MessageType.STATUS_REQUEST )
     pktBuilder.setStatusRequest( CommProtocol.CommandsProtos.StatusRequest.newBuilder() )
     val pkt = pktBuilder.build
     net ! PktSend(1, pkt)
     expectMsg( PktSent(1) ) 
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following error on the last line of the above class

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : org.kdawg.socketclient.NetworkTalker.PktSent required: NetworkTalkerTest.this.FixtureParam => 
     Any
    - type mismatch; found : org.kdawg.socketclient.NetworkTalker.PktSent required: NetworkTalkerTest.this.FixtureParam =>
```

Can anyone help me figure this out ?

Comment: Are you getting this error while compiling in eclipse, or on the console with scalac or sbt?

Comment: Hello Roland, I'm getting the error when compiling with Eclipse.

Comment: I also see the problem when I run "test" in sbt.found   : org.kdawg.socketclient.NetworkTalker.PktSent
[error]  required: NetworkTalkerTest.this.FixtureParam => Any
[error]     expectMsg( PktSent(1) )

Comment: Also moving the test to the file that defines ReaderSourceTest causes the problem to go away. ie, when i write both tests in the same file, they compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Changing imports from

```
import org.scalatest.fixture.FunSuiteLike
```

to

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike
```

worked